# Confused about a badge definition

Tags: discussion

May be a simple question, but I really I do not understand this:

> Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki
>   answers in the privacy tag.

- What is a *non-community wiki*?
- What is this *100 total score of at least 20 non-community wiki*? 100 upvotes or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re community wiki: [see here](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):

> **What are Community Wiki posts?**
>
> Community wiki posts are more easily editable by all users, and do not confer any reputation.

So non-community wiki answers are answers that have not been marked as community wiki.

---

100 total score is not necessarily just upvotes, its the upvotes minus downvotes. So the resulting score that you normally see by default on each post...
And you need to have answered at least 20 questions in that tag (or rather, 20 answers on questions in that tag, you are allowed to have multiple answers on a single question).